# Using Mojolicious commands in system CLI

Tags: perl, mojolicious

My app, [Alambic](https://bitbucket.org/BorisBaldassari/alambic), uses The Great Mojolicious framework, and defines commands that can be executed with e.g. `$ script/alambic alambic init`.

Now when I look at Joel Berger's [Galileo](https://metacpan.org/release/Galileo) and other great pieces of work, I find they have a *system* command that can be directly invoked in a shell, e.g. `$ galileo init`. I looked into the mojolicious doc but found nothing to do that for my app. Now I'm not even sure if it's Mojolicious or the Perl CPAN Build process that makes it possible.. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to place your script somewhere where it can be found on the PATH. Typically that's the bin directory, where it will be installed into the right place. If you want to release to cpan or build a distribution that gets installed using cpan (but not upload to PAUSE) that's the way to go. Look at App::Cpanminus or other things in the App:: namespace for examples. You can browse their code on metacpan.org or their githubs. If you release to CPAN, please move your app into tie App:: namespace too.

Comment: Thanks @simbabque I think I get it now. But what do you mean by a tie App:: namespace? In mojolicious my namespace is Alambic:: so how could I make it a different namespace when building? Would you have any pointer or resource for that? Thanks!

Comment: I didn't say tie. In general it's frowned upon to claim a top level namespace on PAUSE, but seeing as your stuff is pretty large and has a unique name that should be ok. Disregard that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'll provide the complete answer here as a complement to @simbabque 's comment.

So for a Mojolicious application, one has to make it installable (i.e. cpan-aware) in order to have the binaries copied to a directory in the path. More specifically for Alambic I had to:

1. Setup `InstallablePaths` (I decided to go for `Module::Build`), see [the documentation for the module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Plugin::InstallablePaths)
2. Create a `Build.PL` file
3. Run the `Module::Build` sequence to build the module:

> perl Build.PL
>   ./Build manifest
>   ./Build
>   ./Build test
>   ./Build install

During the install step, binaries are copied to a Perl-managed directory that is in the `$PATH`. After that step the `alambic` command was available as a command in my shell.

Note: For one to have her/his own commands available on the CLI, the Mojolicious application has to [define one or more commands](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Guides/Cookbook#Adding-commands-to-Mojolicious) of course.